# Validate basic set operations in JML

Tags: jml

How do I verify basic set operations such as intersect, union and difference in JML tool like OpenJML in which keywords like "\intersect \set_minus \set_union" are not supported?

The Java interfaces on which I want to do validation on looks like this:

```
MySetInterface<S> intersect (MySetInterface<S> set)
MySetInterface<S> union (MySetInterface<S> set)
MySetInterface<S> difference (MySetInterface<S> set)
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to find a functional description for these operations, as for all methods that don't have a direct correspondence in the JML-supported theories. The mathematical definition of the union of two sets, for example, is "the set of all objects that are members of either the one or the other set". I.e., the method `union` could be specified roughly as

```java
/*@ public normal_behavior
  @ ensures this.containsAll(\old(this)) &&
  @         this.containsAll(\old(set)); */
```

and similarly for the other methods, assuming that there is a pure `containsAll` method available. Otherwise, you could use quantified expressions and a pure `contains` method. If you don't have such pure query methods, you would have to expose implementation details like an underlying field, which would make less sense for specifying an interface.

Does this clarify the problem for you?

Comment: What do you think of `@ ensures \result != null&&( \forall java.lang.Object e; ; \result .has(e) <==> this.has(e)||s2.has(e));` 

http://www.eecs.ucf.edu/~leavens/JML-release/javadocs/org/jmlspecs/models/JMLObjectSet.html#intersection(org.jmlspecs.models.JMLObjectSet)

Comment: That should also be a sensible specification, given that your interface has the`has` method. Of course there's more than one way to do it. For judging which one works in your particular case, I'd have to look into your complete source code. The available signature extends your Java model, there aren't that many "generic" JML operators as you seem to think.